# Ajax? loaded content and using the shadowbox

Tags: php, ajax, shadowbox

im using a script called masonry to load posts at mine website dynamicaly when scrolling. This works fine. 
Now I want to open links which are in this post in shadowbox (lightbox like) http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

The problem is that links from posts which are normaly at site are opening in this shadowbox but those from loaded posts are not. Well some time ago I had the same issue with facebook like buttons and I made it working with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
try{
FB.XFBML.parse(); 
}catch(ex){}
});
</script>
```

Now I was looking how to solve this problem with shadowbox and only thing that I've found is this code:

```
$('.klasa').live('click', function () {
Shadowbox.open(this);
return true;
});
```

Which Im supposed to use at the end of the oryginal shadowbox JS code. I did it and it make something, when I click at the loaded links the screen become darker like it should with lightboxes but that's all, it doesnt load the content etc.

Can anyone try to help me? :)